# Configuring puma on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

How can I configure the number of workers, threads and timeout for puma ?
I know I'd have to create a file called puma.rb under config and load the server as puma config/puma.rb. The thing is that I don't have control over the way how the server is initialized. Is there any other way I can configure puma ? I mean, without pointing the configuration file ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start your Rails application from a Puma upstart. There isn't many details in your question, but maybe this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) will help you. Depending on your access rights to the server, might be impossible for you to do.